# Use web parts to show a Word docx file

Tags: web-part

I would like to know if it is possible to show a Word docx file in a web part, just as you can show an Excel sheet

Comment: Hey ....... you did not have a look on my answer yet

Answer (score 0):

You can use `<iframe>` to display docx or excel file. Once I have accomplished it using Content Editor Web Part. Just add a Content Editor Web Part in your page and modify the source like following.

```
<iframe src="/filePath/FileName.xlsx?web=1"></iframe>
```

Remember `?web=1` is very important.

1. `web=0` means file will be downloaded when you hit this `URL` in
   browser.
2. `web=1` means file will be opened in browser using office online.

Same goes for the docx file. You can do it using Script Editor also. Just add a script editor into your page and click on **EDIT SNIPPET**.

[image]

A modal will be opened up. Now add `<iframe>` tag inside it. Finally, you will get your excel/docx file in the page.

[image]

Comment: Looks promising, neet to try it out

Comment: ok try and let me know

Comment: did you try it.. If if worked, then accept. Otherwise consider a bounty @mark